# Why is remote Powershell job consuming so much host memory over time?

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks, jobs

Using powershell, I am creating jobs to run a command block on remote servers.  The command scans folders looking for certain files and returns the contents via the output buffer.  So - I poll the job every so often (say 10s) - and use receive-job to clear the output buffer.  Even then, the memory consumed on the host machine continues to grow by megabytes (memory consumption on client stays low throughout).  I don't see anything in other job buffers (error, warning, etc.).  The total amount of data received via receive-job ends up being maybe 300k... but the memory consumption is around 400mb.  When I remove-job and force garbage collection, the memory is released.

The consumption is gradual, and the growth rate is fairly constant as the job runs.  (well - it jumps 3-6mb every so often...)

```
Invoke-Command ComputerName=$vweb -ScriptBlock {
    param($domainsRoot, $filter, $newFileKey, $sitesList)
    Get-ChildItem -Path $domainsRoot -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$sitesList.Contains($_.Name)} |
        ForEach-Object -Process {               
            Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path (Join-Path $domainsRoot $_) "wwwroot/v/*") -filter $filter -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                    ForEach-Object -Process {
                        Write-Output ($newFileKey + ($_.FullName.replace($domainsRoot,'')))
                        Write-Output (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName)
                    }
        }
} -ArgumentList $domainsRoot, $filter, $global:newFileKey, $sitesList -AsJob -JobName $($vweb)
```

The command block basically scans a folder ($domainsRoot) looking for target folders (found in $sitesList array) - scans a subfolder of that (wwwroot/v/*) looking for files that match a filter ($filter).  (the purpose is to scan iis websites on multiple servers for *.asp files)

Is it something in my command block - or am I misunderstanding how jobs work?

ps version: 5.1.19041.1320, windows 10 host/clients

Comment: More info... I see now that it is the Output field of the child job... which I can't seem to clear out.  ("The state of the current job instance is not valid for this operation.").  If I can't clear this field... my method is just plain bad!  Can anyone confirm if a child job's 'output' can be cleared while the job is running?  Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you can clear the output while the Job is running. As for improving your code, the code itself is fine though could be improved by using direct API calls to `System.IO.Directory`. This is likely to consume a lot less resources and be faster though we would need to have more details on what the scriptblock is doing added to your question, i.e.: what is `$global:newFileKey` and `$sitesList`, why is `(Join-Path (Join-Path $domainsRoot $_) "wwwroot/v/*")` needed ?

Comment: You should also consider returning an object from your scriptblock so that you can later manipulate in your local session, i.e. I presume `$newFileKey + $_.FullName.replace($domainsRoot,'')` is a new name for the file, in that sense you can return `[pscustomobject]@{ filename = $newFileKey + ($_.FullName.replace($domainsRoot,''); filecontent = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw }` from your scriptblock

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon - It does seem the child job output has a clear() function... and it doesn't seem to interfere with the parent job calling receive-job.  (testing that atm).  I'll look into the api call.  The 'newfilekey' is used to denote the beginning of a new file (all files get thrown to output stream).  $sitelist is array of sitenames (folders) i want to process (i.e. just production sites).  the join-path stuff... I only want to find files in a particular sub-folder (in my case, where the site owner can upload custom code).  I'll comment again after testing clear()'s affect.

Comment: Bill, re the `Clear()` method I was unaware of this, though if it helps you should definitely self-answer explaining how it works, re using `System.IO.Directory` I can post an answer later if you really need to improve efficiency and code speed

Comment: I think this `(Join-Path (Join-Path $domainsRoot $_) "wwwroot/v/*")` should be just `Join-Path $_.FullName -ChildPath "wwwroot/v/*"`, is it possible? Note that, `$domainsRoot` is being joined with `$_` which both are the same thing

Answer (score 1):

When you create a remote job, two jobs are created - one for the host and a child job (also on the host) for the remote job.  When I used `receive-job` on the parent, I expected this to clear out all output streams (parent and child).  It turned out that the child job still had a fully populated field `$childJob.output`.

I ended up using `receive-job` on the child job, and then immediately cleared its output using `$childJob.output.clear()`.

In my tests, this didn't have any adverse affects - but, I wouldn't completely trust this method for more critical tasks without better testing.

After I did this, the memory consumption problem was resolved.